# jQuery remove duplicate text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I limit the text displayed in these child elements to display only one? it is currently displaying duplicates. I need to loop through each one and have it only display one text entry.

```
 if ($(this).children('td:nth-child(7)').text() == 'third_party_integration') {
$(this).children('td:nth-child(7)').text(' ');
$(this).children('td:nth-child(7)').text("third_party_integration");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you shouldn't have more than one element on your page with any given `id`. The `<tr>` and `<td>` elements should not share the `id` of `172`.

Comment: Could you created and add a plunkr?

Comment: can you please share the html for this also

Comment: Where is the information (text) that populates the cell coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about writing a function like this, and calling it properly:

```
function ReplaceText (text){
   $('td:contains("' + text + '")').text(text); 
}
```

Comment: @DariusCastillo awesome! :)